# What is the origin of "ortho-," "meta-," "para-," in chemistry?

Tags: terminology, chemistry

The prefix "ortho-" means straight or right; "meta-" means beyond or after; "para-" means beside or along. How, then, did ortho-, meta- and para- come to refer to the carbon positions one, two, and three positions away from a reference point on a benzene?

If we have two groups on a benzene ring immediately beside one another, we do not denote the positions by para-, which would seem logical given its meaning, but instead ortho-. For instance, a benzene ring with two hydroxyl (-OH) groups on immediate positions of a benzene ring can be called para-hydroxybenzene (with the common name "quinone"). What is the etymological history that led to the rather counterintuitive use of these prefixes in organic chemistry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wilhelm  Körner between 1866-1874 was the first to use it to differentiate isomers of benzene rings. Since the Greek suffixes are fairly vague he chose them arbitrary. Its interesting he used orth- for 1,4 isomer, meta- for the 1,2 isomer , and pera-  for the 1,3 isomer. While later chemists used orth- for 1,2 isomer, meta- for the 1,3 isomer , and pera- for the 1,4 isomer. Then in 1879 the  Chemical Society of London officially adopted the backwards notation.

So yea its a arbitrary and backwards system. I got all my info from the one link below.

[The Origins of the Ortho-, Meta-, and Para- Nomenclature](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjl6drurvTPAhXpxlQKHffWAysQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.che.uc.edu%2Fjensen%2FW.%2520B.%2520Jensen%2FReprints%2F126.%2520Othro%2C%2520Meta%2C%2520Para.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGt4Kb4NAwOBG-x9FBKvsVSzM-Faw&sig2=t0Obb8qgxV8CfumN1wOa6A&cad=rja)